# Upload an image and display using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>My webpage!</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />                      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/testcss.css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/testjs.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#img_output').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#img_input").change(function() {
  getURL(this);
});
</script>

<input type='file' id="img_input" />
<img id="img_output" src="#" alt="Image" />
</body>
</html>
```

EDITED to add code.  I just made a single document to test this function alone.  I've tried other examples of code similar, but everything is giving me the same result.

I'm trying to use `js/jquery` and HTML to upload an image from my pc and display it on a page.  For some reason my code doesn't work, but when I search for examples online and literally copy and paste it still is not working.

At this point, I'm not sure where to even look to find what the problem could be. There are no errors showing up when I run ANY of the downloaded code examples nor with the code that I wrote.

I realize this is not the greatest question.  I have spent all day trying over and overwriting what seems like should have taken me 10 minutes to do.  I've read docs, looked at examples, copy and pasted examples and nothing works.  I click the browse button, it opens the image, I select the image and nothing happens.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: for a similar problem I had used this plugin:http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input it's simple and permit 
 to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks PaolaG, I will look at that as well.  I would however like to get to the bottom of why the code doesn't work for me yet works when I run it here.

Answer (score 0):

where is the code?

anyway, you are using J-query local file? CDN?

if any other JS library is added it's could make conflict.

Comment: I did update it with a simple code snippet of what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code snippet we are helpless to help u buddy.
Try & understand following snippet.

```js
function getURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#img_output').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#img_input").change(function() {
  getURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="img_input" />
<img id="img_output" src="#" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: I understand the code and what's going on.  I had originally wrote something similar.  I just copied and pasted your code and it still did not work.  I must be doing something stupid here.

Comment: I have jquery3.3.1 locally, and I also tried your link just to test.  When I run your code snippet it works, but when open it on my browser it does not show up.  However, other jquery functions do work that I've type up. I edited my code above as well and just put the js all on one page to make it easier to see since theres such a small amount of code.

Comment: Oh dear, you forgot to insert jquery CDN. Just add it & try once more.

Comment: Lets debug it. Load jquery file first then others. Keep only your local jquery.js file & comment other js files. Execute & check whether its working or not. Then uncomment one by one js & execute code again. you will get an exact file which is conflicting.

Comment: Everything commented in my scripts, as well as css and still not doing anything.  There's no errors in my console either.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, although it doesn't make much sense why it works.  Below the html I added another <script src="./javascript/testjs.js"> below the file input.  Why does this matter?  Why wouldn't it load for the entire page when I have it loaded in the header?